# Mailchimp create campaign with DrewM PHP wrapper

Tags: php, rest, mailchimp

How do I create a campaign using this wrapper and pass parameters? Ive searched the internet and the documentation but their isn't enough information or example code

```
$mc->post('campaigns');
```

just returns an error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is for api v3

Comment: Is this what you're using? https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Comment: yes it is the wrapper im using

Comment: This wrapper just makes it easier to format HTTP requests. Have you read the docs from Mailchimp?  Specifically, what you want to do is covered here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/#campaigns

Comment: Ive been looking here..
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/

I just need a plain example of how to make the call with the right parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've authenticated, etc., you can just add in your parameters like the Mailchimp docs show:

```
$result = $MailChimp->post("campaigns", [
          'type' => 'regular',
          'recipients' => ['list_id' => 'xxx'],
          'settings' => ['subject_line' => 'Your Purchase Receipt',
                         'reply_to' => 'orders@example.com',
                         'from_name' => 'Customer Service']
            ]);
```

The wrapper doesn't really do anything; it just provides a standard way to pass these arrays to Mailchimp.

Comment: Thanks, Thats exactly what I needed!

Comment: You're welcome - please mark the question as answered when you're able